# Why when I sort a list full of 0's it gets mixed up?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm trying to rate some Gin's by popularity, I read in the Gin list as a text file and each Gin starts with a popularity of 0, but when I sort the list it comes out mixed, not in it's original alphabetical order as it is if not sorted.

No sorted -

[image]

Here is the code I'm using -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GinListClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("the text file holding Gin's, Country, ABV and the Price")]
    public TextAsset ginTextFile;
    [Header("the Lists, public for debugging")]
    public List< string > ginString = new List< string >();

    private int rating;
    private int linesInFileCount;

void Start () 
{
    rating = 0;
    List<GinList> gins = new List<GinList>();

    string[] linesInFile = ginTextFile.text.Split('\n');

    foreach (string line in linesInFile)
    {
        linesInFileCount++;

        ginString.Add(line);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < linesInFileCount; i++)
    {
        gins.Add( new GinList(ginString[i], ginString[i+1], ginString[i+2], ginString[i+3], rating+Random.Range(0,100)));
        i+=4;
    }
    gins.Sort();
    //gins.Reverse();

    Debug.Log("A .. Gin count is " + gins.Count);

    foreach(GinList gin in gins)
    {
        Debug.Log(gin._ginName + " - " + gin._country + " - " + gin._abv + " - " + gin._price + " - " + gin._pop);
    }
    gins.Clear();
}
```

}

And -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GinListClass : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("the text file holding Gin's, Country, ABV and the Price")]
public TextAsset ginTextFile;

[Header("the Lists, public for debugging")]
public List< string > ginString = new List< string >();

private int linesInFileCount;

void Start () 
{
    List<GinList> gins = new List<GinList>();

    string[] linesInFile = ginTextFile.text.Split('\n');

    foreach (string line in linesInFile)
    {
        linesInFileCount++;

        ginString.Add(line);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < linesInFileCount; i++)
    {
        gins.Add( new GinList(ginString[i], ginString[i+1], ginString[i+2], ginString[i+3], Random.Range(0,100)));
        i+=4;
    }
    //gins.Sort();
    //gins.Reverse();

    Debug.Log("A .. Gin count is " + gins.Count);

    foreach(GinList gin in gins)
    {
        Debug.Log(gin._ginName + " - " + gin._country + " - " + gin._abv + " - " + gin._price + " - " + gin._pop);
    }
    gins.Clear();
}
```

}

If i give the Gin's a rating they sort correctly.

Can someone pleas point me in the right direction, thank you.

[image] [image]

Comment: Please tag with programming language tag

Comment: It's not unlikely that the sorting algorithm used is quicksort, which is not stable. You probably need to use a sorting algorithm named something like `StableSort` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort algorithms are stable, some are not. Probably, the sort algorithm that is used by that library is not stable, i.e., it may reorder items that compare equally.

As a solution, you could order first by popularity, but if they have the same popularity, you sort by name. I don't know C# (or whatever you are using) but it should be something like this pseudo-code

```
int compare(const myobject & i1, const myobject & i2) {
    if(compare(i1.popularity, i2.popularity) == 0) {
        // reverse sort by popularity
        return -compare(i1.popularity, i2.popularity);
    }   
    return compare(i1.name, i2.set2id);
}
```

use it as

```
gins.Sort(compare);
```

Edit: Solution

Comment: Thanks for the input, if it were not a stable algorithm would each debug be different from the last? As I've done 100 debugs, all being the same each time sort is called.

Comment: Yes, not stable != random. As I wrote, not stable only means that items that compare equally may be reordered arbitrarily. However, most sorting algorithms are implemented such that they are deterministic, i.e., if you run the algorithm multiple times on the same input, you always get the same output.

Comment: @KevinGriffiths: Add added pseudo-code for a solution